# How do I read in a text file from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, java.util.scanner, file-read

I created a scanner to read in a text file from the first element in the command line, but it results in a `FileNotFoundException`. How do I format it to where it accepts this file?

Here is my code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

For example, if the file name is `Hello.txt`, I put `Hello.txt` as the first element in the command line.

Comment: Have you tried printing the args array? What are you getting for element 0? Does that file actually exist?

Comment: Is `Hello.txt` in your current running directory?

Comment: Where is your Hello.txt located? Since you pass only the file name, but not further context of the location of the file, the JVM tries to read it from some default locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.  "build.xml" is a file I happen to know exists in my project's folder.  Try printing the "absolute path" of the file, it'll show you where Java is looking, which might be different than what you are expecting.

```
public class ScratchPad {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      System.out.println( new File("build.xml").exists() );
      System.out.println( new File("build.xml").getAbsoluteFile() );
   }

}
```

Output:

```
run:
true
C:\Users\Brenden\Google Drive\proj\tempj8\build.xml
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```